# Gmail support for Attaching Files from Android Application

Tags: android, gmail, email-attachments

I have read all of the similar posts in regards to sending an attachment from internal memory using the GMAIL app. I implemented the content provider suggestion and still cannot get the attachment to actually send using GMAIL.

When passing the intent, everything seems like it is working, the file just gets removed when sent and the recipient sees no attachments. This code works fine on the native Android Email application.

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Android Manifest:

```
<provider
android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="/data/user/0/com.myapp/files" path="."/>
 </paths>
```

java:

```
ShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        File fileToSend = new File("");
        File dir = getFilesDir();
        File[] subFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (subFiles != null) {
            for (File file : subFiles) {
                if (file.getName().equals(curveChosen)) {
                    fileToSend = file;
                }
            }
        }
        File Path = new File(view.getContext().getFilesDir(),"");
        File newFile = new File(Path,fileToSend.getName());
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(view.getContext(),"com.myapp.fileprovider", newFile);

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Email Text");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Select Email Application"));
    }
});
```

Comment: I recommend replacing `name="/data/user/0/com.myapp/files"` with something simpler that does not involve path segments, such as `name="stuffToSend"`. Also note that there is no requirement for any `ACTION_SEND` implementation to support both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` on the same `Intent`.

Comment: I have tried this and still have the same issue.